# Templating models for Custom Models C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a collection of model which are inherited by base class containing Createddate, modifieddate, id, createdby and modifiedby. Everytime i create i have to keep all those fields manually! Now what i want to do is create a generic class that has to assign those fields. How will I be able to achieve that?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the values and timing of your assignment? Because initially, using the base class constructor might be more appropriate than some generic class that is (how??) related to your other classes.

Comment: @grek40 Basically, I am using it in Create action assigning all the mentioned values and then storing it in database. But i have around 50 models that has create action. Everytime i have to copy paste those 5 lines code to assign those values.

Comment: Well here's the deal: copy-paste your 5 code lines once more - into the question. It may help understanding your current approach. Best, also copy the surrounding Create action and a sample usage scenario